# How do I label a constraint and a view in iOS to make any sense out of the visual debugger mess

Tags: ios, constraints

coinsRightToSuperviewConstraint?.label = "coins2superview"

gives me "label is inaccessible due to internal protection level.

Is it only possible to give views and constrains names in xib editor to make
any sense or the view constraint maze in visual debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it only possible to give views and constrains names in xib editor to make any sense or the view constraint maze in visual debugger?

Not only is it possible, it's essential.

Let's start with views. You can set a view's "label" in Interface Builder:

[image]

The value that you enter here is used in the "document browser" of Interface Builder.

But that doesn't help you when debugging in code. For that, here's an extension that gives a view a `name` property:

```
extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var name : String? {
        get { return self.layer.name }
        set { self.layer.name = newValue }
    }
}
```

That's an inspectable property, so it shows up in Interface Builder.

Now let's talk about constraints. If you make a constraint in code, you'll probably call `activate` on it; here's an extension that lets you add an identifier at that time:

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    func activate(withIdentifier id: String) {
        (self.identifier, self.isActive) = (id, true)
    }
}
```

If you create a constraint in Interface Builder, the constraint's identifier is directly available already:

[image]

Finally, don't forget about the View Debugger. It's an important way to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

You can add `identifier` instead of `label`:

```
coinsRightToSuperviewConstraint?.identifier = "coins2superview"
```

Comment: for some reason it says Value of type 'Constraint' has no member 'identifier'

Comment: @AntonTropashko What is `Constraint` ? It should be `NSLayoutConstraint`

Comment: I got screwed by SnapKit. With raw NSLayoutConstraint without a wrapper it does work. Thanks, upvoted

Answer (score 1):

Not really clear what you're going for, but here is an example that shows setting the `.identifier` on a constraint:

```
class ConstraintIDViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let label = UILabel()
    var labelTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "Testing"
        label.backgroundColor = .cyan
        
        view.addSubview(label)
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        labelTopConstraint = label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0)
        labelTopConstraint.identifier = "LabelTopID"
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            labelTopConstraint,
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
        ])
        
        
        view.constraints.forEach { c in
            if c.identifier == "LabelTopID" {
                print("found constraint:", c)
            }
        }

    }
    
}
```

the debug console output is:

```
found constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000036dc870 'LabelTopID' UILabel:0x7fd404d09770.top == UILayoutGuide:0x600002cc01c0'UIViewSafeAreaLayoutGuide'.top + 40   (active)>
```

and Debug View Hierarchy shows:

[image]